yolo training with low precision and low map
I am using YOLOv5 to train a model to recognize cards in a card game. I started with the pre-trained model yolov5s.pt and my dataset consists of 138 images. However, the accuracy and mAP are very low during training, starting from 2.35e-05 and 2.27e-05 respectively, and after 80 epochs, they only reached 0.0169 and 0.0547.
I can't figure out what the problem is. Can someone help me?
Here's the picture of the training batch image and the output table.


By the way I only want to recognize the discard not the handcard.
I've tried to change the batch size etc. But it didn't change a lot.

I cannot help much with YOLOv5.  I maintain and use Darknet/YOLO, which is both faster and has better precision than what you'll get from Ultralytics/Roboflow and other python-based YOLO frameworks.
But I do have YouTube videos where I discuss using YOLO to detect playing cards.  Some of this will apply to you regardless of which version of YOLO or framework you are using.
Things to note:

Sizing the network is very important:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3Trxxt9RzE
What happens if you don't size your network correctly (this might explain the results you are seeing):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcW7OrKaYiA
context is important -- why things outside of your bounding boxes is also important:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auEvX0nO-kw

Also see the YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/
You don't mention how you've setup your classes.  Do you have classes for all 52 cards?  Or do you have Ace-to-King and then the 4 suites, which you then plan on combining to make a card?  Either way, only having 138 training images doesn't seem like much, but especially if you used the first option with 52 classes, then that would mean only 2 examples of each card, which isn't enough.  See this:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#how_many_images

Thank you very much for your answer. I initially believed that a relatively small dataset would be sufficient for these consistent images on the same gaming platform, but it now appears that this might not be enough.
I have 54 classes for all 54 cards including the jokers. And in each training images theres more than 1 card, normally ranging  from 3 to 15 cards. I will try to label more images and increase the dataset size to see if this improves the results. Thank you again for your helpful advice.
